# asp.net razor For Each syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have some asp.net razor syntax problems. I have this JavaScript array, want to convert it to razor syntax:

```
var Vendors = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C"
                ];
```

To:

```
var Vendors = [
        @For Each Vendor In ViewBag.VendorsList

           @Vendor.Name + ","

        Next
        ];
```

But there is some errors, what is the right way? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It's recommended to process your data elsewhere, the presentation layer should preferably do only one thing, the UI. If this array is needed on the client-side, then you'll have to return it from your C# code (server-side). Else if you have an array on the client-side and wish to do something with it, just post it to the server and do your processing there.

It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I have array of strings, that arrive in the viewbag from the controller back to the view. Wanna insert it to JS array called Vendors. and than use the Jquery Autocomplete on that array. thx

Comment: I suggest adding another action method, which returns a Json object containing your array or what have you. When the page loads, request this method from JavaScript via ajax, grab the data and update your UI.  Or you can render your array in a hidden field, then read its value from JavaScript and extract the array. Whatever matches your taste better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a list of values in a server-side variable and you want to inject that into the view's JS code as an array....

so (I've coded this blind so it might need some tweaking)...

```
 @{
      List<script> mylist = ViewBag.VendorsList == null ? new List<script>() : (List<script>)ViewBag.VendorsList;
      string delim = "";
}


<script>
var vendors = [
     @foreach(var item in mylist) {
       string theOutput = delim + "\"" + item + "\"";
       delim = ","
     <text>
     @theOutput
     </text>

     }
];
</script>
```